# Is there a Bayes rule for when some of the random variables are discrete and continuous?

Tags: reference-request

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable, and $Y$ be a discrete random variable

Is there a "Bayes rule" for:

$P[Y | X = x]$

where $P$ is the probability mass function of $Y$?

Any reference help!

Comment: I believe $P(Y \in A | X = x) = P(Y \in A, X = x) / P(X = x)$ still holds.

Comment: Unfortunately, since $X$ is continuous, $P(X=x$ is zero (as is $P(Y\inA,X=x)$ , and so you must do something else to avoid division by zero.

Comment: Regarding @MarkFischler's answer, you could further compute the limit of a sequence of sets $B_n \subset R_X$ such that: $x \in B_n$, and $B_n+1 \subset B_n$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X \in B_n) = 0$. If the limit exists, you could get $P(Y=y | X=x)$.

Comment: Typo correction: it should be: $B_{n+1} \subset B_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper statement of Bayes law for this case would be that:

Given any continuous variate $X$ with range $R_X$ and discrete variate $Y$ and some joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ (they need not be independent) then for any set $B \subset R_X$
such that $P (X \in B) > 0$ and any value $y$,
$$
P( Y = y | X\in B )= \frac{P( (Y = y) \wedge (X\in B) )}{P(X\in B)}
$$ 
You can also go the other way, provided that $y$ is in the range of $Y$ with non-zero probability:
$$
P(X\in B | Y = y )= \frac{P( (Y = y) \wedge (X\in B) )}{P(Y = y)}
$$

Comment: Is there a way to re-write this using the PDF of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

There's also another identity in the case when $\ X\ $ has a density function  $\ \phi\ $ with respect to some measure $\ \mu\ $ on its codomain.  When this is the case $\ Y, X\ $ will also have a *joint* mass-density function $\ \psi\ $ satisfying the equation  $\ P\left((Y=y)\, \land \left(X\in B\right)\right)=\int_B\ \psi\left(y,x\right)d\mu\left(x\right)\ $, and we then have
$$ P\left(Y=y\,\vert\, X=x\,\right)= \frac{\psi\left(y,x\right)}{\phi\left(x\right)}\ $$
for all $\ y\ $ and $\mu$-almost all $\ x\ $.